# How can I make a GL_LINE_LOOP anti-aliasing?

Tags: c++, opengl-es, glut

Here is some openGL code that I've created. The routine is two sideways houses. I am trying to make only one of these houses that look nice with no pixels showing. I want to use antialiasing but I cant figure out why it doesnt work.. Any help?

```cpp
void myDisplay()
{
    //glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 0); // XYZ middle, top
    glVertex3f(-0.05, -.15, 0); // XYZ left, bottom
    glVertex3f(.15, .05, 0); // XYZ right, bottom
    glEnd();
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex3f(0, -.1, 0); // XYZ left, top
    glVertex3f(.1, 0, 0); // XYZ right, top
    glVertex3f(0.2, -.1, 0); // XYZ right, bottom
    glVertex3f(0.1, -.2, 0); // XYZ left, bottom
    glEnd();
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);

    glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex3f(-.2, 0.1, 0); // XYZ left, top
    glVertex3f(-.1, .2, 0); // XYZ right, top
    glVertex3f(0, .1, 0); // XYZ right, bottom
    glVertex3f(-.1, 0, 0); // XYZ left, bottom
    glEnd();
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
    glAlphaFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 0);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA_SATURATE, GL_ONE);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glVertex3f(-.2, .2, 0); // XYZ middle, top
    glVertex3f(-.25, .05, 0); // XYZ left, bottom
    glVertex3f(-.05, 0.25, 0); // XYZ right, bottom
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc,
    char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutCreateWindow( "basic template 1" );
    glutDisplayFunc( myDisplay );
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Was any of the questions helpful? You can vote on multiple answers (by the arrows on the left of the answer). Furthermore you can accept one single answer (by the check mark on the left of the answer)

Answer (score 0):

It is not allowed to call anything between [`glBegin`/`glEnd`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBegin.xml) except those operations which set vertex attributes and specify a vertex ([`glVertex`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertex.xml), [`glColor`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColor.xml), [`glNormal`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glNormal.xml), [`glTexCoord`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexCoord.xml), ...).

For [Multisample anti-aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multisample_anti-aliasing), the `GLUT_MULTISAMPLE` flag has to set in [`glutInitDisplayMode`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node12.html). Optionally, the number of samples can be set by [`glutSetOption`](http://openglut.sourceforge.net/group__state.html). This has to be done before [`glutCreateWindow`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node16.html):

```cpp
glutSetOption(GLUT_MULTISAMPLE, 8);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_MULTISAMPLE);
glutCreateWindow( "basic template 1" );
```

By default multisampling is enabled. It can be enabled and disabled by [`glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE)` / `glDisable(GL_MULTISAMPLE)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnable.xml):

[image]

```cpp
void myDisplay()
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    glDisable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);

    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 0); // XYZ middle, top
    glVertex3f(-0.05, -.15, 0); // XYZ left, bottom
    glVertex3f(.15, .05, 0); // XYZ right, bottom
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex3f(0, -.1, 0); // XYZ left, top
    glVertex3f(.1, 0, 0); // XYZ right, top
    glVertex3f(0.2, -.1, 0); // XYZ right, bottom
    glVertex3f(0.1, -.2, 0); // XYZ left, bottom
    glEnd();

    glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);

    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex3f(-.2, 0.1, 0); // XYZ left, top
    glVertex3f(-.1, .2, 0); // XYZ right, top
    glVertex3f(0, .1, 0); // XYZ right, bottom
    glVertex3f(-.1, 0, 0); // XYZ left, bottom
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex3f(-.2, .2, 0); // XYZ middle, top
    glVertex3f(-.25, .05, 0); // XYZ left, bottom
    glVertex3f(-.05, 0.25, 0); // XYZ right, bottom
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutSetOption(GLUT_MULTISAMPLE, 8);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_MULTISAMPLE);
    glutCreateWindow( "basic template 1" );
    glutDisplayFunc( myDisplay );
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it probably isn't supported. glHint is sadly just a hint (no one needs to actually implement it).

If you want smooth lines, your best bet is probably to use a multisampled framebuffer. This can be done as an offscreen framebuffer if you wish, although if you are using freeglut, then you can initialise the window to enable multisampling. e.g.

```cpp
int main(int argc,
    char** argv)
{
   glutInit(&argc, argv);
   glutSetOption(GLUT_MULTISAMPLE, 8);
   glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_MULTISAMPLE);
   glutCreateWindow("basic template 1");
   glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);
   glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
   glutMainLoop();
}
```

Also make sure you delete the call to 'glutInitDisplayMode' in your display function (You should only call it once, prior to creating the window).

Comment: It *is* possible to deliberately switch smoothing on- and off. The rest of what you say is correct. (you're only wrong about the "isn't supported") But also have a look at my observations in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing Anti-Aliasing in OpenGL. Some are described [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18777/how-do-i-implement-anti-aliasing-in-opengl)

For your example, I suggest to move *all* init functions to the main function. In your original example the `glClear()` was missing and set *before* the clear-color function. This makes the screen black.

To do aliasing the way you want, to have anti-aliasing "on" for one house and "off" for the other, you have to specifically enable or disable the smoothing for the elements you require.

I also suggest to put them together and *before* the actual drawing functions. You also should not put enable/disable functions between `glBegin/glEnd` blocks. This also helps for clarity of code.

I've changed color of one house, so you see the black house with no anti-aliasing, but the blue house has.

```
void myDisplay()
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glDisable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
    glDisable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glDisable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);

    glColor3f(0, 0, 0);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex3f(0, 0, 0); // XYZ middle, top
    glVertex3f(-0.05, -.15, 0); // XYZ left, bottom
    glVertex3f(.15, .05, 0); // XYZ right, bottom
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex3f(0, -.1, 0); // XYZ left, top
    glVertex3f(.1, 0, 0); // XYZ right, top
    glVertex3f(0.2, -.1, 0); // XYZ right, bottom
    glVertex3f(0.1, -.2, 0); // XYZ left, bottom
    glEnd();

    glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
    glHint(GL_POINT_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);

    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);

    glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
    glHint(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);

    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex3f(-.2, 0.1, 0); // XYZ left, top
    glVertex3f(-.1, .2, 0); // XYZ right, top
    glVertex3f(0, .1, 0); // XYZ right, bottom
    glVertex3f(-.1, 0, 0); // XYZ left, bottom
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex3f(-.2, .2, 0); // XYZ middle, top
    glVertex3f(-.25, .05, 0); // XYZ left, bottom
    glVertex3f(-.05, 0.25, 0); // XYZ right, bottom
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}




int main(int argc,     char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutCreateWindow("basic template 1");
    glutDisplayFunc(&myDisplay);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

**Update:**

The other answers are "technically correct" but there are a few caveats and observations I've made:

- `glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLING)` is no longer supported in newer OpenGL standards (it used to be up to 1.3 IIRC). Whether you can still use it depends on your actual implementation.
- the `glutSetOption()` function is only available in "freeglut" when using `#include "GL/freeglut.h"` not in original `glut.h`. But my observation on Windows is that there is no difference between specifying multisampling or not. So I assume it is "default-ON".

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have used this method and it works great